# How to send and retrieve decimal values in json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I am sending price in decimal value according with some other fields to an API and showing the price in another project, i am able to send decimal values but when I retrieve it shows non decimal value

[image: see the price]

the above which I send price

[image: recieved]

the price retrieved without decimal values

how to rectify it ?

my sending code is :

```
var reg_price = $("#reg_price").val();
var f_price = parseFloat(reg_price);
data.price = f_price;
```

Comment: The problem is your API server-side.  There's nothing special you have to do to send numeric values with decimal points in JSON.  I'd caution you though... usually you don't deal with money in floating point, because of rounding errors.  It's pretty common to use a straight integer value instead.

Comment: Sounds like a back end problem to me

Comment: It looks like your server is returning the value (or modifying it at some point) as an integer. What backend/server language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify`.  Send it like a string

```
var reg_price = $("#reg_price").val();
var f_price = parseFloat(reg_price);
data.price = JSON.stringify(f_price); //JSON.stringify
```

Comment: when i srtingify and send it shows the following error ; Can not construct instance of int from String value '34.67': not a valid Integer value

Comment: @SabrilogeshK There's your problem...treating it as `int` and not floating point

Comment: what is your api's language @SabrilogeshK